# Applying sequential numbering as attribute values of child nodes in one parent node, and then applying these in a different order in a sibling node

Tags: xml, xslt

Good morning, I have the following (bilingual) XML snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tmx version="1.4">
<body>
    <tu>
        <prop type="x-Context">-2050338055591740051, -2050338055591740051</prop>
        <prop type="x-Origin">TM</prop>
        <prop type="x-ConfirmationLevel">Translated</prop>
        <tuv>
            <seg>
                <ele>The text </ele>
                <ele>
                    <ph x="0" type="QIAsymphony"/>
                </ele>
                <ele> goes </ele>
                <ele>
                    <ph x="0" type="470"/>
                </ele>
                <ele> here </ele>
                <ele>
                    <ph x="0" type="471"/>
                </ele>
                <ele>.</ele>
            </seg>
        </tuv>
        <tuv>
            <seg>
                <ele>El texto </ele>
                <ele>
                    <ph x="0" type="QIAsymphony"/>
                </ele>
                <ele> se mete </ele>
                <ele>
                    <ph x="0" type="471"/>
                </ele>
                <ele> aquí </ele>
                <ele>
                    <ph x="0" type="470"/>
                </ele>
                <ele>.</ele>
            </seg>
        </tuv>
    </tu>
</body>
 </tmx>
```

I would like to first of all number the x attribute values of the ph elements in the first tuv/seg node, from 1 to 3 (in this case).

However, the result I am getting is this:

```
<tuv>
            <seg>
                <ele>The text </ele>
                <ele>
                    <ph x="2" type="QIAsymphony"/>
                </ele>
                <ele> goes </ele>
                <ele>
                    <ph x="4" type="470"/>
                </ele>
                <ele> here </ele>
                <ele>
                    <ph x="6" type="471"/>
                </ele>
                <ele>.</ele>
            </seg>
        </tuv>
```

This is based on the following XSLT Stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>



 <xsl:template match="tmx">
 <tmx><xsl:attribute name="version"><xsl:value-of select="./@version"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</tmx>
 </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="body">
<body>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</body>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tuv">
<tuv>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</tuv>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="prop">
<prop><xsl:attribute name="type"><xsl:value-of select="./@type"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</prop>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="tu">
<tu>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</tu>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tuv[1]/seg">


<seg>
<xsl:for-each select="ele"> 
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="child::ph">


<ele><ph><xsl:attribute name="x">

<xsl:number/>
</xsl:attribute>

<xsl:attribute name="type">

<xsl:value-of select="ph/@type"/>
</xsl:attribute>


</ph></ele>
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>   
 <xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="child::text()">

<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>   

</xsl:for-each>



</seg>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In order words, I need the following result:

```
  <tuv>
            <seg>
                <ele>The text </ele>
                <ele>
                    <ph x="1" type="QIAsymphony"/>
                </ele>
                <ele> goes </ele>
                <ele>
                    <ph x="2" type="470"/>
                </ele>
                <ele> here </ele>
                <ele>
                    <ph x="3" type="471"/>
                </ele>
                <ele>.</ele>
            </seg>
        </tuv>
```

Finally, based on the type attribute values in the first tuv/seg node, I need to apply the corresponding x values to the x attributes in the second tuv/seg node (which in this case will be in a different order):

```
 <tuv>
            <seg>
                <ele>El texto </ele>
                <ele>
                    <ph x="1" type="QIAsymphony"/>
                </ele>
                <ele> se mete </ele>
                <ele>
                    <ph x="3" type="471"/>
                </ele>
                <ele> aquí </ele>
                <ele>
                    <ph x="2" type="470"/>
                </ele>
                <ele>.</ele>
            </seg>
        </tuv>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25378898/numbering-placeholders-sequentally-in-a-node-based-on-sequence-in-which-they-ap

Answer (score 0):

To answer your most immediate question, the reason you are getting the numbers 2, 4, 6 is because of how you use the `xsl:number` command

```
<xsl:attribute name="x">
   <xsl:number/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

You are positioned on an `ele` element at this point, so will be counting all `ele` elements, when it looks like you only want to count ones with child `ph` elements. Therefore you need to do this

```
<xsl:attribute name="x">
   <xsl:number count="ele[ph]"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

However, before answering your next issue about numbering the second `tuv` element, you need to learn about the XSLT identity transform. Rather than write explicit templates for every single node you wish to copy, you just have a single one to cover all those you wish to change without amending. So you could write your current stylesheet as just this...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tuv[1]/seg/ele[ph]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <ph type="{ph/@type}">
                <xsl:attribute name="x">
                   <xsl:number count="ele[ph]"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </ph>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But to re-number the second `tuv` element, consider using a key to look up the `ele` elements in the first `tuv` element

```
<xsl:key name="ph" match="tuv[1]/seg/ele/ph" use="@type" />
```

Then, to do the numbering, you would have to count the number of preceding siblings for each element

```
    <xsl:attribute name="x">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(key('ph', ../@type)/../preceding-sibling::ele[ph]) + 1" />
    </xsl:attribute>
```

This would work in both `tuv` elements.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="ph" match="tuv[1]/seg/ele/ph" use="@type" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tuv/seg/ele/ph/@x">
        <xsl:attribute name="x">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(key('ph', ../@type)/../preceding-sibling::ele[ph]) + 1" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Great, that worked a treat! :) I'd like to take it one small step further, and  try to get it to work on the same XML file, minus the ele elements, which I added myself to make numbering easier to perform. Do you think that might be possible to implement?

Comment: Yes, that should be possible! If you can't work it out, feel free to ask a whole new question!